# visual studio c++ does it build only files shown in the tab?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ and was following the instruction steps [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4s55GgAg0I&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&index=7)

The situation was I have math.cpp file where contains two functions.

One of those function was already in the other cpp file in the same project so I have removed it.

The build worked however, when I tried to recreate the removed cpp with the same name, it said this already exsits. In the file explorer, the file was there not deleted completely.

Now I'm confused how this visual studio building works.

Does it only builds the cpp files which is shown in the tab even though some files not included may exist in the same folder?

I was wondering wouldn't this cause a problem in the future when you are programming and some of the files not shown in the tab?

Comment: Only the cpp files in the project are used when building. What's on disk in the same directory doesn't matter. Removing a file from the project does not delete it on disk.

Comment: It builds the files that are part of the project. See what files are listed in the "Solution Explorer" as part of the project

Answer (score -1):

Removing the file does not delete it from the directory, it removes it from the project. So it's still there in the directory. When you right-click on the file and attempt to remove it, it should give you the option to delete the file or remove it. Now that you have removed it right click on the source files folder and add then existing item. Now navigate to where the cpp file is and add it back.